# What are notions of "well-behavedness" for distributions?

Tags: probability, reference-request, definition

When talking about functions, there are many notions that are interpreted as well-behaved, such as increasing, continuous, integrable, and many of these terms can be directly understood in some context.

What would be equivalent notions for distributions? There is often an intuitive appeal to a notion of sufficiently random, or naturally random process, but I don't know any such notions.   One requirement can be that there's a continuously differentiable definition. For continuous spaces, it can be "no set of measure $0$ has probability more than $0$". In some context, having one distribution if tails and another distribution if heads would be acceptable, and not in other contexts.

So what are the rigorous mathematical definitions that capture various notions of well-behaved distributions?

Comment: If by distributions you mean "probability measures", then each can be decomposed into 3 parts: pure point, absolute continuous and singular continuous (Cantor distribution is the classical example of the latter). Excluding the 3rd option makes distribution "well-behaved" in some sense. There is a classification of the tails of the distribution: 1. Sub-gaussian: $E(e^{aX^2})<\infty$ for some $a>0$ 2. Sub-exponential:$E(e^{tX})$ exists for some $t\ne 0$, + fat/heavy/long-tailed distribtions. This includes "sub-exponential" class with the same words having very different meaning.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you very much for these great pointers. 
I hadn't mentioned the tail classification as it is more akin to the growth rate of a function.
It's not directly in my question, but do you have examples of results that hold for all non-singular distributions? Pathological objects usually give some enlightening examples.

Comment: Can't think of any apart from non-singular distributions having pdfs. Because CDF is always increasing, is of finite variation and all you need is to integrate against it, I can't think of any "pathological" objects - again, except for something like Cantor distribution that is a bit hard to think about.